# Package 'PaymillWrapper 3.3.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'

Tags: .net, mvvmcross, .net-framework-version, .net-standard-2.0

I have a `Xamarin.Android` project and I use `MVVMCross`.

I have the latest MVVMCross version - `6.0.1.`

I'm trying to use NuGet packages, in particular [Paymill](https://paymill.com).But I have a problem:

```
Package 'PaymillWrapper 3.3.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' 
instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. 
This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

I know that I can use `NoWarn="NU1701"`,but it's not what I need.The Paymill package doesn't work correctly,I can't use it in my project.

[image]

Does it mean that this package doesn't support `.NETStandard,Version=v2.0` at all? Or am I missing some details/tweaks for this problem?

Comment: fork code on github and compile against .net standard 2.0

Comment: PaymillWrapper is .NET 4.5. Not compatible with your targets.